# How to show a video on a Jupyter widget on a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Assume I have a folder with 4 video files (named like "movie1.mp4", "movie2.mp4" etc.)

I want to use ipywidgets to let the user control which video he desires to see. Like this:

```
import ipywidgets as wd
from IPython.display import HTML

def showvideo(i):
    HTML("""<video width="100" height="100" controls><source src="movie{}.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>""".format(i))

wd.interact(showvideo, video_number = [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

This doesn't work.
but simply calling

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""<video width="100" height="100" controls><source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>""")
```

works

Is there some python magic that I need to call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually displaying the result. Jupyter automatically attempts to display the result of the last line of code in a cell, so that's why your HTML is displaying when doing it manually, but if you are calling it progrmamatically or your HTML isn't on the last line, you have to manually call `display()` on your HTML.

Additionally, you aren't specifying the parameter correctly. The parameter name in the function has to match what you supply to `interact`. Changing your code to this should work:

```
def showvideo(video_number):
    display(HTML("""<video width="100" height="100" controls><source src="movie{}.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>""".format(video_number)))

wd.interact(showvideo, video_number = [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```